# Device does not receive push notification in Xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to implement a application with push notifications using Firebase, but the app doesn't receive any notification from server (no method was called)

my `AppDelegate.cs`

```
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate , IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, IMessagingDelegate 
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        App.Configure();

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {
            var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                Console.WriteLine(granted);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
            var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
        }

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;
        Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;

        Messaging.SharedInstance.ShouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;

        Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.Notifications.ObserveTokenRefresh((sender, e) => {
            var newToken = Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newToken);
        });

        return true;
    }

    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Registered for remote notifications");
        Console.WriteLine(deviceToken.GetBase64EncodedString(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None));
        Console.WriteLine(deviceToken);
    }

    [Export("messaging:didReceiveMessage:")]
    public void DidReceiveMessage(Messaging messaging, RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("iOS 11 Foreground");
    }

   [Export("userNotificationCenter:DidReceiveRemoteNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received a notficaiton");
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
    }

    [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void WillPresent(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handling iOS 11 foreground notification");
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound | UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
    }

    [Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler();
    }

    public void ApplicationReceivedRemoteMessage(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
    }
```

[image]

The p12 file has already been uploaded and the "Enable push notifications" checkbox has already checked. What is missing in my code?

Comment: Do you mean your iPhone never receives notification or it can receive but these methods never calls?

Comment: Did Firebase show the message had been sent? And did you add the GoogleService-Info.plist as a BundleResource to your app? And are ANY of the events firing, such as the token registration receipt?